# source command is not recognizing the file although it exists, No such file or directoryline

Tags: linux, bash

I have simplified the problem by removing domain-specific details to be easier to be reproduced.

I have a file called items that has the following content:

```
itemA
itemB
```

And two other files called itemA.settings and itemB.settings that have the following content:

itemA.settings content

```
export title="Title itemA"
```

itemB.settings content:

```
export title="Title itemB"
```

I have created a script(configure-all-items.sh) that reads the content from items file and loops through each element like below:

```
#!/bin/bash

$itemListDIR="../path"

itemList=$(cat $itemListDIR/items);

for(item in itemList)
do
    echo "Configuring item: $item"
    prepare-item.sh $item
done
```

prepare-item.sh uses the title to create a file for each item with the title as filename. The content of the prepare-item.sh is like below:

```
#!/bin/bash
$item="$1"
source "$item.settings"
echo "Item has title: $title" > title.txt
```

When executing the configure-all-items.sh script two files are created:

`Title itemA.txt` that the content:

```
Item has title:
```

Title itemB.txt that has  the content:

```
Item has title: Title itemB
```

Also, I get this error when `itemA.settings` is being sourced

`No such file or directoryline xx: ./../../../itemA`

Comment: Check your script for CRLF line breaks, fix with `dos2unix`

Comment: `for(item in itemList)` is invalid syntax. This can't be your real code.

Comment: ...also, `$item=$1` isn't a valid assignment -- it doesn't change `$item` at all; it would need to be `item=$1`, without the leading `$`.

Comment: (and `for item in $itemList`, while more correct, is _still_ bad practice; it would do things like replace a `*` in the list with a list of filenames in the current directory -- proper practice would be something like `readarray -t itemList <"$itemListDir/items"` and then `for item in "${itemList[@]}"; do`)

Comment: (but yes, stray carriage returns caused by your file being saved as a DOS/Windows text file instead of as a UNIX one are the obvious immediate problem, in addition to everything else)

Comment: Thank you all for your help. The bash script had the correct style ending the problem was I forgot to check the style ending in the items file and that was causing this problem. After fixing the style ending in the items file, everything is working as it should.